# Create multidimensional array from multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge, array-merge

I have two arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => label [1] => data )
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

And I need merge them in a array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => 1 [data] => 2  ) )
```

I have tried:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($inputs); $i++) {
    $new = array($cols[$i] => $inputs[$i]);
    $data[] = $new;
}
```

Any help is welcome ;)

Comment: please first post your attempts

Comment: Are you sure you want `Array ( [0] => Array ( [label] => 1 [data] => 2  ) )` instead of `Array ([label] => 1 [data] => 2)`?

Comment: you're right. And I have tried: for ($i=0; $i < count($inputs); $i++) {
            $new = array($cols[$i] => $inputs[$i]);
            $data[] = $new;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [array_combine](https://php.net/array_combine):

> Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its
> values

```
$arr1 = array(0 => 'label', 1 => 'data');
$arr2 = array(0 => 1, 1 => 2);
$arr3 = array_combine($arr1, $arr2);

print_r($arr3);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [label] => 1
    [data] => 2
)
```

[Try it](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d32bb153691aad4e996e9b451c47595352ac710c)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so if you want to use a loop

```
$array1 = ['label', 'data'];
$array2 = [1, 2];

$array_merged = [];

foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    $array_merged[$value] = $array2[$key];
}

var_dump($array_merged);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c4e5bc71df53ebdafb0a54d43c3eadb4ea4cd241